# how to check if custom post type exists in wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to know is there any wordpres function that allow me to check whether the given string is title of any wordpress custom post type or not.

Answer (score 4):

you can do it with Function **post_type_exists**
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_type_exists

**Examples**

```
if ( post_type_exists( 'book' ) ) {
   echo 'the Book post type exists';
}
$exists = post_type_exists( 'post' );
// returns true

$exists = post_type_exists( 'page' );
// returns true

$exists = post_type_exists( 'book' );
// returns true if book is a registered post type

$exists = post_type_exists( 'xyz' );
// returns false if xyz is not a registered post type
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for this query. Wordpress has inbuilt query which allows you to check whether the post exists in wordpress or not.
The function I have found is post_exists(). Which is located into wp-admin/includes/posts.php

Comment: That's great that it works for you. However, wanted to note that you need a title of a post for this to work.